# How the design of ship help to survive in the water

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, marine-engineering

I have seen bigg cargo, and other ships, and I like their structure very much., a question come sin my that why the ship structure is like this.

[image]

Can anyone explain what was reason for this. I am not an engineer is this field but still I am interested to know why is it so.

Edit:) I mean, why the shape of ship is in this given in the picture.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? the shape? the material? some specific detail? and what do you mean with "survive in the water"?

Comment: Down vote for what. Can anyone explain me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the end part of the ship during the construction and is not finished yet.

This part when finished will be called Stern.

The stern houses the rudder and the propellers and follows the keel.

It is designed to have a streamlined narrow shape under the water to help reduce the drag of the ship and vibration due to the rotation of the propellers and the reaction of the rudder. It is designed to deliver a smooth stream of water to the propellers to reduce turbulence. Hence the horizontal structural steel stiffeners are wider her for strength.

The top deck which is dry and above the water level flares out wide to accommodate more surface for containers or volume for the oil if this will be a tanker.

Here is a diagram from the site www.marineinsight.com.

[image: diagram from, https://www.marineinsight.com/]

Comment: Pretty sure it's a bow section that will feature a bulbous bow. There isn't enough space for the power plant for that to be a chunk of stern.

Comment: see image here - https://www.cruisemapper.com/images/news/2259-589da40ca54.jpg

Comment: @Phil Sweet, it could be. But I think more likely it is the stern for two reasons, the water in front of the ship and the size of the stiffeners. The propeller and rudder are structurally the strongest part of the ship. That is were the huge hydrolic forces of steering and propulsion impart on the ship.